# Getting multiple post types and taxonomies post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I want to display latest news/alerts post on my homepage and I need some help.

I am currently only displaying news with `post` post-type using below code. This is working perfectly. The problem occurs when I want to use more than one post-type. once I modify as `'post_type' => array('post','blog')`, nothing appears. The reason why it does not show is `$term = get_the_category();`. Once I remove this whole section for color with `<a></a>`. It works perfectly.

So I believe I have to specify the taxonomies. Because in `Post` I have tax as `category` and in `Blog` I have tax as `blog-category`. I could not get these two in same time.

So how can I call two taxonomies in `$term = get_the_category();`

Thank you from now

```
<div class="news-area">
<div class="items clear">

<?php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
));
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
  $info = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_post_info', true); if (!$info) $info = array();
  $post_elem=get_post();
  ?>
<div class="item <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) echo 'has-image' ?>">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="content">
          <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
              <?php the_post_thumbnail('full') ?>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <?php
          $term = get_the_category();
          $term = $term[0];
          $color = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'color', true);
          ?>
          <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term) ?>" class="category" style="background-color: <?php echo $color ?>">
              <?php echo $term->name ?>
          </a>

          <h2 class="title">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="underline"><?php the_title() ?></a>
          </h2>

          <div class="description">
              <?php //$except_meta=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),"_excerpt") ?>
              <?php //echo "Aaaaaaa".$query->the_post()->post_excerpt ?>
              <?php if($post_elem->post_excerpt!=""): ?>
                  <?php  the_custom_excerpt($post_elem->post_excerpt, $length =80); ?>
              <?php else: ?>
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

          <div class="date"><?php echo get_the_date(et_get_option('_date_format')) ?></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sohrab how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot add a comment, so I'll post it as an answer. Try:

```
<?php
      $term = get_the_category();
      if ( ! empty( $term ) ) {
          $term = $term[0];
          $color = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'color', true);
          ?>
          <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term) ?>" class="category" style="background-color: <?php echo $color ?>">
          <?php echo $term->name ?>
          </a>
          <?php
       }
       ?>
       <h2 class="title">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="underline"><?php the_title() ?></a>
       </h2>
```

This will at least prevent  from showing / executing when $color is not set.

Comment: Thanks @Vos, so but this is not solving my problem, I want to show the tag for blog and post too. 'blog-category' and 'category' how can I define these two taxonomies in there?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I just solved it by changing

```
$term = get_the_category();
```

to

```
$term = get_the_terms($ID,array('blog-category','category'));
```